# Is the title "Acts of the Apostles" treated as plural or singular?

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, titles

When I speak of one book titled *Acts of the Apostles*, should I say: "*Acts of the Apostles* contain" or "*Acts of the Apostles* contains" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Book titles are treated as singular even if they are plural. It's like you replace the title with "the book". "The book contains", thus, "*Acts of the Apostles* contains".

Comment: ok, my australian colleague was not sure...